# c# using generics to access table

Tags: c#, class, generics, datatable

I have two classes, like this

```html
public class Cash
    {
        public Guid Id { get; }

        public Cash(Guid id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
      }
      
   public interface ICashRepository 
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<Cash>> GetAllAsync();
        Task<Cash> GetOneAsync(Guid id);
    }
  
   public class CashRepository
    {
        private readonly DataContext _db;

        public CashRepository(DataContext db)
            => _db = db;

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Cash>> GetAllAsync()
            => await _db.Cashes.ToListAsync();

        public async Task<Cash> GetOneAsync(Guid id)
            => await _db.Cashes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    }


  public class Cash2
    {
        public Guid Id { get; }

        public Cash2(Guid id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
      }
      
   public interface ICash2Repository 
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<Cash2>> GetAllAsync();
        Task<Cash2> GetOneAsync(Guid id);
    }
  
   public class Cash2Repository
    {
        private readonly DataContext _db;

        public Cash2Repository(DataContext db)
            => _db = db;

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Cash2>> GetAllAsync()
            => await _db.Cashes2.ToListAsync();

        public async Task<Cash2> GetOneAsync(Guid id)
            => await _db.Cashes2.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    }
```

I want to do a Generic method, so i can use it to different classes...

```html
    public class BaseRepository<T>
    {
      T value = default(T)
     private readonly DataContext _db;
     
      public CashRepository(DataContext db)
            => _db = db;
     
        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync()
            => await _db.Cashes.ToListAsync();

        public async Task<T> GetOneAsync(Guid id)
            => await _db.Cashes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    }
```

I need to replace

```
public CashRepository(DataContext db)
```

with  generic Constructor so it can call `CashRepository` and `Cash2Repository`

And also need to replace table `Cashes` to a Generic Table...

```
_db.Cashes.FirstOrDefaultAsync
```

How can i do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Entity Framework. It has [`DbContext.Set<TEntity>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-3.1) method, allowing you to do exactly that:

> Creates a `DbSet<TEntity>` that can be used to query and save instances of `TEntity`.

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetAllAsync() => _db.Set<T>.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks...
the constructor  public CashRepository(DataContext db)  => _db = db; I should replace with DbSet<T> ?

Comment: @Diego I think not.

Comment: thanks... How can  i replace public CashRepository(DataContext db)  => _db = db; with a Generic construction...Cash is being replace with <T>
thanks

Comment: @Diego `CashRepository<T>(DataContext db) where T : class` ?

Comment: thanks, I just added more example..  think I need a generic method that it can call CashRepository and Cash2Repository inside BaseRepository<T> class. I need to call CashRepository  and Cash2Repository constructor using T...
Thanks

Comment: @Diego not following you.